# Why I do not need a configuration bean for Environment interface

Tags: java, spring

I don't understand why I don't need configuration bean when I want to use Environment interface? For example, to use environment variable "filename" I have to @Autowired Environment in my class

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

public BigDecimal getRate(String currency, Date rateDate) {
    fileName = env.getProperty("filename");
    System.out.println(fileName);
    return ...
}
```

Can You explain me why I do not need configure any bean in this case? How to check in Spring code or documentation why exactly I don't need it.  Thanks in advance

Comment: It is one of several special objects, just like the `ApplicationContext` which you don't need to configure yourself or the `ResourceLoader`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the built-in `ApplicationContext` implementations come with a set of pre-registered bean definitions. These are listed in the documentation, [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation):

> You can also use `@Autowired` for interfaces that are well-known
>   resolvable dependencies: `BeanFactory`, `ApplicationContext`, **`Environment`**,
>   `ResourceLoader`, `ApplicationEventPublisher`, and `MessageSource`. These
>   interfaces and their extended interfaces, such as
>   `ConfigurableApplicationContext` or `ResourcePatternResolver`, are
>   automatically resolved, with no special setup necessary.

It's not obvious, but since `@Autowired` works, so does getting beans of these types through [`ApplicationContext#getBean(..)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-). In other words, they all get their own bean definition. The bean implementation depends on the type of context being initialized.